# I need to print this cout statement at the end "This is not an option" and return back to the beginning to bring up the menu

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<ctime>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // Variable declarations
    unsigned seed = time(0);

srand(seed);

int answer = 0;
int number1 = rand() % 500 + 1;
int number2 = rand() % 500 + 1;
int useranswer = 0;
int option;

cout << "  Math Tutor Menu" << endl;
cout << "------------------------------" << endl;
cout << "1. Addition problem" << endl;
cout << "2. Subtration problem" << endl;
cout << "3. Multiplication problem" << endl;
cout << "4. Division problem" << endl;
cout << "5. Quit this program" << endl;
cout << "-------------------------------" << endl;
cout << "Enter your choice (1-5): ";

cin >> option;
if(0<option<6){
    
    while(option = option){
    
    if (option == 1){
        number1 = rand() % 500 + 1;
        number2 = rand() % 500 + 1;

        cout << "   " << number1 << endl;
        cout << "+  " << number2 << endl;
        cout << "______" << endl;

        answer = number1 + number2;
        cout << "Please enter the answer: ";
        cin >> useranswer;

        if(useranswer == answer){
            cout << "Congratulations! That's the correct answer." << endl;
        }
            else{
                cout<< "Sorry. The correct answer is " << answer <<endl;
            }
        
        break;


    } else if (option == 2){
        number1 = rand() % 500 + 1;
        number2 = rand() % 500 + 1;
        cout << "   " << number1 << endl;
        cout << "-  " << number2 << endl;
        cout << "______" << endl;

        if(number1>=number2){
        answer = number1 - number2;
        cout << "Please enter the answer: ";
        cin >> useranswer;
        }
            else{
                answer = number2 - number1;
                cout << "Please enter the answer: ";
                cin >> useranswer;
            }
        if(useranswer == answer){
            cout << "Congratulations! That's the correct answer." << endl;
        }
            else{
                cout<< "Sorry. The correct answer is " << answer <<endl;
            }
        
        break;
        
    } else if (option == 3){
        number1 = rand() % 100 + 1;
        number2 = rand() % 9 + 1;
        cout << "   " << number1 << endl;
        cout << "x  " << number2 << endl;
        cout << "______" << endl;

        answer = number1 * number2;
        cout << "Please enter the answer: ";
        cin >> useranswer;

        if(useranswer == answer){
        cout << "Congratulations! That's the correct answer." << endl;
        }
            else{
                cout<< "Sorry. The correct answer is " << answer <<endl;
            }
        
        break;
    } else if (option ==4){
        number2 = rand() % 9 + 1;
        number1 = number2*(rand() % 50 + 1);
        cout << "   " << number1 << endl;
        cout << " ÷ " << number2 << endl;
        cout << "______" << endl;

        answer = number1 / number2;
        cout << "Please enter the answer: ";
        cin >> useranswer;

        if(useranswer == answer){
            cout << "Congratulations! That's the correct answer." << endl;
        }
            else{
                cout<< "Sorry. The correct answer is " << answer <<endl;
            }
        break;
    } else if (option==5){
        cout << "Exiting program."<< endl; return 0;
    }
else{
    
    cout << "That is not a choice." <<endl; 

}
        
return 0;
}
}
}
```

I am struggling to print the bottom statement "That is not a choice" and to bring it back to the menu for the user to choose 1-5. This is a math program I have almost completed, this is the final part I need to complete, thank you in advance! I am editing this in notepad++. I know there is some more improvements I could add but it is function other than this final error statement I am trying to build in.

Comment: `while(option = option)` There it seems that you are missing something. First I think you want to compare something instead of assigning? And also you "compare" (or assign) the same variable to itself

Comment: The expression `0<option<6` will not work as you expect. It's actually equal to `0 < (option < 6)`. I.e. you compare the value `0` against the result of the comparison `option < 6`. You need to chain multiple conditions using the logical AND operator `&&` (which any [decent book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) should have taught you).

Comment: Then think about *where* you have the loop. How would the program loop back to the printing the menu if there's no loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add a while or do-while loop. like this.

```
while (true)
{

    cout << "  Math Tutor Menu" << endl;
    cout << "------------------------------" << endl;
    ...
    ...
    else{
    cout << "That is not a choice." <<endl; 
    }
}
```

If I were you I would have used switch-case instead of if-else.

Comment: I switched it to that, and when I input an option that is not 1-5, it does bring up the new menu, but it now does not print the message.